# Summing Nested Json

Tags: ruby, json

So, we have a json response like:
[Link to Formatted Sample Json](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=ueviiTEg)

```
{"C":{"1":{"1":{"A":[18],"B":[18],"C":[20],"D":[24],"E":[24],"F":[2],"G":[15],"H":[21],"I":[8]},"2":{"A":[9],"B":[26],"C":[12],"D":[10],"E":[10],"F":[3],"G":[7]},"3":{"A":[6],"B":[4],"C":[5],"D":[3],"E":[4],"F":[13]},"4":{"A":[3],"B":[2],"C":[5],"D":[13],"E":[5],"F":[5],"G":[4],"H":[7]},"5":{"A":[10],"B":[10],"C":[10],"D":[10],"E":[10],"F":[15]},"6":{"A":[10],"B":[7],"C":[5],"D":[4],"E":[7],"F":[10],"G":[4],"H":[18]},"7":{"A":[2],"B":[18],"C":[6],"D":[3],"E":[2],"F":[5],"G":[7],"H":[5],"I":[17]},"8":{"A":[20],"B":[2],"C":[10],"D":[3],"E":[5],"F":[10]},"Review 1":{"A":[30]},"Review 2":{"A":[30]}},"2":{"1":{"A":[2],"B":[3],"C":[10],"D":[10],"E":[10],"F":[15]},"10":{"A":[10],"B":[3],"C":[3],"D":[3],"E":[20]},"11":{"A":[2],"B":[6],"C":[5],"D":[10],"E":[10],"F":[13]},"2":{"A":[5],"B":[5],"C":[5],"D":[6],"E":[6],"F":[12],"G":[6],"H":[8]},"3":{"A":[3],"B":[4],"C":[8],"D":[3],"E":[2],"F":[3],"G":[12]},"4":{"A":[10],"B":[10],"C":[10],"D":[11],"E":[10],"F":[20]},"5":{"A":[8],"B":[4],"C":[8],"D":[5],"E":[14]},"6":{"A":[5],"B":[10],"C":[14],"D":[14]},"7":{"A":[3],"B":[5],"C":[8],"D":[9],"E":[10],"F":[16]},"8":{"A":[2],"B":[2],"C":[4],"D":[2],"E":[3],"F":[6],"G":[8]},"9":{"A":[2],"B":[6],"C":[5],"D":[11]},"_mex":{"1":[9]},"Review 1":{"A":[31]},"Review 2":{"A":[30]},"Review 3":{"A":[30]}},"3":{"1":{"A":[1],"B":[1],"C":[1],"D":[2],"E":[6]},"2":{"A":[2],"B":[4],"C":[7],"D":[8],"E":[8],"F":[9]},"3":{"A":[5],"B":[8],"C":[11]},"4":{"A":[10],"B":[10],"C":[11]},"5":{"A":[2],"B":[4],"C":[5],"D":[1],"E":[3],"F":[8]},"6":{"A":[4],"B":[8],"C":[8],"D":[12],"E":[8],"F":[20]},"7":{"A":[25],"B":[12],"C":[13],"D":[15],"E":[12],"F":[20]},"8":{"A":[5],"B":[3],"C":[3],"D":[7],"E":[1],"F":[1],"G":[1],"H":[1],"I":[1],"J":[3],"K":[17]},"mex2":{"A":[7]},"_mex2":{"A":[7]},"Review 1":{"A":[30]},"Review 2":{"A":[30]}},"4":{"1":{"A":[10],"B":[2],"C":[2],"D":[8],"E":[3],"F":[3]},"2":{"A":[5],"B":[10],"C":[5],"D":[10],"E":[10]},"3":{"A":[6],"B":[4],"C":[3],"D":[11]},"4":{"A":[4],"B":[4],"C":[4],"D":[4],"E":[11],"F":[21]},"5":{"A":[5],"B":[8],"C":[3],"D":[4],"E":[5],"F":[7],"G":[15],"H":[5],"I":[5],"J":[6],"K":[14]},"6":{"A":[2],"B":[4],"C":[3],"D":[2],"E":[2],"F":[3],"G":[4],"H":[4],"I":[4],"J":[4],"K":[7],"L":[34]},"_mex2":{"A":[7]},"Review 1":{"A":[77]}}}}
```

What I want to do is sum all the numbers contained in the response.

Ive tried iterating through all the nesting but I was only been able to do one section. Using:

```
@number = 0
json["C"]["1"]["1"].each do |key, val|
    val.map do |x|
        @number+=x
    end
end
#=> 150
```

Any suggestions how I would do that same for json["C"]["1"]?

Comment: For clarification, do you mean that you'd like to specify which level of the JSON hierarchy you'd like to sum (no matter how high up or low in the hierarchy it is)? Meaning if you specified `json["C"]` you'd sum pretty well everything, or if you specified `json["C"]["1"]["1"]` or `json["C"]["1"]["2"]`, you'd only sum what was in that level?

Comment: @Teeg I'd like to sum everything so json["C"]["1"].

Comment: Don't put a link to your JSON sample; Links break and then your question will be nonsense, plus you're forcing people who want to help you to chase down the information needed to help you, which wastes their time. Summarize the JSON sample in your question where it's easy to see and won't be subject to link-rot.

Comment: @theTinMan The json is too big and formatted so I cant really post it here:L

Comment: You can't reduce it? Really? I looked at it and it's quite easily reduced.

Comment: I put the unformatted version above! Hope it helps someone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the JSON, here's code that'll walk the hash:

```
hash = JSON.parse(json)

def sum_hash(h)
  sum = 0

  h.each do |k, v|
    sum += v.is_a?(Hash) ? sum_hash(v) : v.first
  end

  sum
end

sum_hash(hash) # => 1964
```

The hash has to be walked, and each value inspected since it's irregular. If the value is another hash `sum_hash` calls itself with that sub-hash, which then begins walking the sub-hash received.

For each hash value that isn't a hash, the integer is retrieved from the array using `first` and added to `sum`. When the method exits it returns the current value of `sum`, so, once the hash has been descended into, successive `sum` values get added.

Reducing the JSON makes it a LOT easier to make sure the code is doing the right thing:

```
json = '
{
  "C": {
    "1": {
      "1": {
        "A": [1],
        "B": [1]
      },
      "2": {
        "A": [1],
        "B": [1]
      },
      "Review 1": {
        "A": [1]
      },
      "Review 2": {
        "A": [1]
      }
    }
  }
}
'
```

Running the above code with that says the sum is `6`.

Comment: Thanks! But I keep getting "`+': nil can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)"

Comment: Well, the code above works, so either your JSON has an entry that evaluates to nil during parsing, or maybe your version of Ruby is out of date.